# How to add attribute to DynamoDB CDK table [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I am new to creating CDK and I am trying to create a CDK for a dynamoDB table.
I have table design like this.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "ccd")
public class abcd {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    private String id;
 
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ack")
    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "ack", globalSecondaryIndexName = "ack-i")
    private String acknowledged;
 
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Go")
    private String go;
 
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ac")
    private long ac;
 
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "amt")
    private long amt;
   
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "cr")
    private int cr;
   
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ttl")
    private long ttl;
}
```

In the CDK my app.ts is something like this

```
export class MyCdkAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create the DynamoDB table
    const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'MyTable', {
      tableName: 'ccd',
      partitionKey: {
        name: 'id',
        type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
      },
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    // Add global secondary index for "ACK" attribute
    table.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({
      indexName: 'ack-i',
      partitionKey: {
        name: 'ack',
        type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
      },
    });
}
```

How should I add other attributed to the table ? For example Go, ac, ttl etc.

When I am doing table.addAttributes or attributeDefinitions : []
I am getting error in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add non-key attributes to your tables definition. As DynamoDB is schemaless, you need only define your keys, all other attributes can be altered and changed as you like on a per-item basis while inserting or updating the data.