# put_item DynamoDb with FastAPI post request

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, fastapi

I've set up a backend using FastAPI and Pydantic

```py
class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str 
    age: int 
    year: str

... 

@app.post('/create-student/{student_id}')
def create_student(student_id : int, student : Student):
    db = connect_ddb() #Boto3 instantiates dynamoDb resource
    student_obj = json.loads(student)
    try:
        db.put_item(
            Item = {f"{student_id}": student_obj}
        )
        return db.get_item(student_id)    
    except: 
        return {"error": "Unable to put data in Ddb"}
```

Now when I try to test this functionality using

```py
def put(item, id_, db=db):
    obj = json.dumps(item)
    db.put_item(Item={f"{id_}": obj})

put(id_=4, item={
    "name": "Guy",
    "age": 17,
    "year": "year 12"
})
```

I receive the following `'{"error": "Unable to put data in Ddb"}'`.

So we can safely conclude that the Db connection was successful. However, I'm unable to insert the object into DynamoDb. Because an error post-connection was returned.

Is there a way to raise the specific error? (DynamoDb would need to return it via FastAPI.)

Or better yet, should the Item parameter in put_item method be formatted differently?

The connection set up using

```py
def connect_ddb():
    ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    table = ddb.Table('myTable')
    return table
```

Comment: That is not how you indicate an item to the table's put_item call. It should be a dict of key/value pairs e.g. `{ "id": 4, "name": "james", "age": 14 }`

Comment: @jarmod not going to work for me; need to be able store nested json objects of varying depths and attributes. This is fine according to an AWS employee: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705267/how-to-add-attribute-to-dynamodb-cdk-table-typescript

Comment: Instead of masking the actual error that happened with your own (probably wrong) message, print the actual error: `... except Exception as error: print(error)`

Comment: Yes, you can store nested attributes using a Map. If your table has a simple primary key of "id" then something like `{ "id" : student_id,  "student": student_obj }`

Comment: @DeepSpace, do you mean return error or print error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the exception because you make a read directly after write, which is eventually consistent. If you want to do a read directly after right, be sure to set the consistent parameter to true.

But this is not how to check if an item persists in DynamoDB, you should receive a 200 response from DynamoDB, then you are certain the item persisted, no need to read every time.

The `Item` your passing to PutItem does not look to be following the correct syntax.  `id` and `item` should be at the same level.

Comment: Strongly consistent you can do immediately after. But why are you doing it?